# How to read a .zip or .gz file from IBM Object Store Bucket in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, unzip, gunzip

The references that I found in the following links say about reading from Bucket as an object.

If I could read as `createReadStream` as we do for local machine files, I can unzip it. But I could not find a way to read Object store bucket content ( a zipped file) as `readStream`.

If I read with getObject operation, I can not get the original text content once I unzip the object (or Buffer part)
Can anyone please help?

The used code:

```js
var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: itemName, 
};

return await cosClient.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        console.log(typeof data, ">>>><<<<<<", data);           // successful response
            var decompress = zlib.createUnzip(data)
            console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<", typeof decompress, decompress.toString())
            var json = JSON.stringify(decompress['_outBuffer'])
            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", typeof json, json)
            console.log("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||", json.toString('utf8'))
    }
});
```

The response body:

```js
object >>>><<<<<<
{
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 'Tue, 08 Dec 2020 01:53:06 GMT',
  ContentLength: '538',
  ETag: '"e55d7f8febfba8c58aec3d64cae70b0f"',
  ContentType: 'application/x-zip-compressed',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 0c ba 76 51 d7 de aa 2a 7c 01 00 00 15 07 00 00 65 63 77 2e 6a 73 6f 6e ed 94 3d 4f c3 30 10 86 ... 480 more bytes> 
}
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< object [object Object]
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> string {"type":"Buffer","data":[192,113,174,210,185,2,0,0,240,243,155,210, .... 0,0,0]}
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||| {"type":"Buffer","data":[192,113,174,210,185,2,0,0,240,243,155,210,185,2,0, .... 0,0,0]}
```

Links:

[Calling the getObject operation](https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-js/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)

[Get file contents of particular item](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-node)

Comment: What object do you get in `data` in a response?

Comment: Please add this output to your post as formatted text. It'a hard to read it in comments

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly; I have updated. **Code:**
`console.log(typeof data, ">>>><<<<<<", data)`
**Response:**
`object >>>><<<<<<{ AcceptRanges: 'bytes', LastModified: 'Tue, 08 Dec 2020 01:53:06 GMT', ContentLength: '530', ETag: '"e55d7f8febfba8c58aec3d64cae70b0f"', ContentType: 'application/x-zip-compressed', Metadata: {}, Body: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 0c ba 76 51 d7 de aa 2a 7c 01 00 00 15 07 00 00 65 63 77 2e 6a 73 6f 6e ed 94 3d 4f c3 30 10 86 ... 480 more bytes> }`

Comment: So you already have data as Buffer

Comment: Yes, I do @Anatoly. the Buffer is for the zipped data. I need the unzipped text.

Comment: So you can use any package that can unzip from Buffer. Look at `jszip`/`jszip2` for instance

Comment: I will try jszip and will update, thank you.
Earlier I tried zlib.createUnzip, it did not complain. But the output I am getting is not readable text, as you can see.
**Format of my original text:**
`[
    {
        "interval_start": 101000226523,
        "interval_end": 101000226549,
        "Instance": "XXX",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to unzip a binary content you got from Object Store you can try to use `jszip` package like this:

```
var JSZip = require("jszip");
JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body)
.then(function(zip) {
    // you now have every files contained in the loaded zip
    zip.file("hello.txt").async("string"); // a promise of "Hello World\n"
});
```

See [example](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html)

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly
I can unzip both .zip and .gz files with a file-path on the local machine (with `readStream ` for local files.)

But for IBM Cloud Object Bucket gives me the content as Object only as I have shown you in the output example (which contains Buffer part).

Is there any way to unzip from this output (Object) that we get from Cloud Bucket?
Thanks

Comment: You should get `Body` prop from a response and turn it into zip object using JSZip: `JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body).then(...`

Comment: Thank you; I am trying that now

Comment: Great! it worked.
Thanks a million :D
```            JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body)
                .then(function (zip) {
                return zip.file("project.json").async("string");
            }).then(function (text) {
                console.log(text);
            });```

Comment: Do we have such a package for .gz files? Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at `zlib` that is already in Node.js?

Comment: zlib worked for gunzip of .gz; thanks. Just a very small issue: I can not return the output for some reason.

`                zlib.gunzip(data.Body, (err, buffer) => {
                    myJson = buffer.toString('utf8');
                    console.log(myJson);
                    return myJson;
});
               

console.log(">>>>>>", typeof myJson, myJson);`

Comment: You need to wrap a call with a callback into `Promise`